# Setting project folder as standard when using command line in Java?

Tags: java, python, command-line, cmd, directory

I am using a provided python script in a project which I call using

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd C:\\Users\\Kevski\\Desktop\\EKI Projekt\\Route Planning\\tools\\ && python draw.py coordinates.route");
```

It creates an image from the coordinates.route file which I later use again in Java. It also works fine - on my computer. My question is can I automatically let the path above be adjusted to the project folder so that it works on any machine?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what `Properties` are for. You could define the path in a property file and read it and then use it in the command. 
As a simple example, you cold pass the path from java command line (if running from command line) or in web/app server configuration file for `-D` parameter. When in command line, send path as a parameter as :

`java -Dpath.to.command="/usr/local/" YourClassName`

In the class, the property can be read as :

`String path = System.getProperty("path.to.command");`

If path is not null, construct the complete command using variable `path` and proceed. Thus you have externalized the path, and then can be passed from command line in any environment.